# Vaadin Spring war file not loading to TomCat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, vaadin, war, vaadin23

I have been working on my application for quite a while without building a war file. About 4 months ago, built the war, my Tomcat server picked it up just fine.

I've since moved to Java 17, Spring 2.7.8 and from Vaadin 22 to Vaadin 23.3.6. So, last week was the week to go to production. Having done this many times, was not expecting any issues. *Silly me*.

Finally got so frustrated I downloaded the simplest app from https://vaadin.com/hello-world-starters, "Vaadin 23 - Spring Boot". This compiled to a jar and works just fine.

I followed this list of steps to get a war file built:

1. Changed from jar to war packaging in the pom
2. Added the spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency with provided
3. Build using mvn clean package -Pproduction and it built without errors.
4. Moved the .war to the Tomcat webapps directory.

from the localhost log:

```
16-Feb-2023 17:15:00.211 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing AtmosphereFramework
16-Feb-2023 17:15:00.265 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
16-Feb-2023 17:15:00.278 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletContextListeners]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application Lookup instance is not found in VaadinContext. The instance is suppoed to be created by a ServletContainerInitializer. Issues known to cause this problem are:
- A Spring Boot application deployed as a war-file but the main application class does not extend SpringBootServletInitializer
- An embedded server that is not set up to execute ServletContainerInitializers
- Unit tests which do not properly set up the context for the test

        at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ApplicationConfiguration.lambda$get$0(ApplicationConfiguration.java:54)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServletContext.getAttribute(VaadinServletContext.java:73)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ApplicationConfiguration.get(ApplicationConfiguration.java:48)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.createPropertyDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:82)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletDeployer$StubServletConfig.createDeploymentConfiguration(ServletDeployer.java:185)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletDeployer.lambda$getServletConfigurations$0(ServletDeployer.java:280)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletDeployer.getServletConfigurations(ServletDeployer.java:279)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletDeployer.contextInitialized(ServletDeployer.java:194)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletContextListeners.contextInitialized(ServletContextListeners.java:44)
    ..... bunches more ......
16-Feb-2023 17:15:00.288 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeStartupListener]
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeStartupListener.contextDestroyed(DevModeStartupListener.java:89)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4817)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5478)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1024)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1911)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.
             ........... and more ...........
```

Spelunking the web, tried a bunch of other things like adding a dependency for spring-boot-starter-web. No joy.

Here is the pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- Project from https://start.vaadin.com/project/d1a77315-5545-41f3-9d35-e61444d0cfb9 -->
    <groupId>com.example.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <name>myapp</name>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>23.3.6</vaadin.version>
        <!-- this parameter is needed as spring-boot bom overwrites it -->
        <selenium.version>4.5.3</selenium.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->

        <!-- Main Maven repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
        </repository>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>-->
        
        <!-- -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Include JUnit 4 support for TestBench and others -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Clean build and startup time for Vaadin apps sometimes may exceed
                     the default Spring Boot's 30sec timeout.  -->
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5321</jvmArguments>
                    <wait>500</wait>
                    <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--
                Take care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports in
                package.json and main.js files.
                It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet.
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>it</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                            <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</project>
```

Using Tomcat Tomcat/9.0.68, confirmed it is java 17 with "java -cp catalina.jar org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo"

Comment: Have you tried creating a project with War packaging from here to compare? https://start.spring.io/

Comment: Did you notice the suggestion in the error message to make sure the Spring Boot application class extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`?

Comment: @Leif: yes, have ensured that is correct.

Comment: @Frettman: no, I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your application class extends SpringBootServletInitializer

and add:

```
    @Bean
SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer( DataSource dataSource,
        SqlInitializationProperties properties, SamplePersonRepository repository ) {

    // This bean ensures the database is only initialized when empty
    return new SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer( dataSource, properties ) {

        @Override
        public boolean initializeDatabase() {
            if ( repository.count() == 0L ) {
                return super.initializeDatabase();
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Also note that Tomcat 9 is what you need for compatibility with versions in Vaadin and SpringBoot.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I must have something else fubar on my machine. Good guidance on Tomcat 9. Discovered that somewhere while spelunking the internet so went to 9.0.71. Not critical for me at the moment so may push off further pursuit to vaadin 24 and spring 3 as that will have a bunch of issues to resolve.